# Create a substitution template with Adobe Illustrator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way for my designer to create an Adobe Illustrator export or particular file type that can contain variable substitution so images or text within the template image can be replaced at runtime to generate new png's for a website?

Once I have the template I want to bind data at the time of request to generate a new image.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Adobe Scene 7 with Illustrator to upload / convert .ai files into .fxg which parameterizes any layer / object in Illustrator art and allows you to modify the items at runtime via an addressable URL.  This is a paid service, but I imagine slimmed down version of this could be accomplished using an SVG implementation.